# Docker 1.0 CentOS 6.5 “unable to mount sys as readonly” when running image

Tags: centos, docker, centos6

$ sudo docker run -i -t centos /bin/bash

Get the following error message:

2014/06/19 20:40:34 unable to remount sys readonly: unable to mount sys as readonly max retries reached

Added the the following parameter to /etc/sysconfig/docker and restarted the service (sudo service docker restart)

other_args="--exec-driver=lxc"

My /etc/sysconfig/docker looks like this (the --selinux-enabled was already in there before)

other_args="--exec-driver=lxc"
other_args="--selinux-enabled"

Answer (score 10):

your `/etc/sysconfig/docker` needs to look like this:

```
other_args="--exec-driver=lxc --selinux-enabled"
```

otherwise it will not work.

Comment: don't forget to restart docker after the change: sudo service docker restart

Answer (score 1):

I also see this when I upgraded to 1.0 from 0.11 on RHEL 6.5

--selinux was already set in /etc/sysconfig/docker and I had to set --exec-driver=lxc for conatainers to started working again.